# Unable to insert multiple point to influxdb bad timestamp

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb, influxdb-python

Some one kindly help me.
I am trying to insert multiple point to influx db, but I am getting bad timestamp error

> 'ovrs,M=91091096
> s=1593683375,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=1,e=1593683479,V=1,d=104
> 1593660200000000000\novrs,M=91091096
> s=1593678600,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=0.208953,e=1593683375,V=0,d=4775
> 1593660200000000000'

Tried to insert

> INSERT 'ovrs,M=91091096 s=1593683375,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=1,e=1593683479,V=1,d=104 1593660200000000000\novrs,M=91091096 s=1593678600,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=0.208953,e=1593683375,V=0,d=4775 1593660200000000000'
>
> ERR: {"error":"unable to parse ''ovrs,M=91091096
> s=1593683375,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=1,e=1593683479,V=1,d=104
> 1593660200000000000\novrs,M=91091096
> s=1593678600,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=0.208953,e=1593683375,V=0,d=4775
> 1593660200000000000'': bad timestamp"}

Tried to inset without code

> INSERT ovrs,M=91091096 s=1593683375,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=1,e=1593683479,V=1,d=104 1593660200000000000\novrs,M=91091096 s=1593678600,shift="02-07-20-S2",p
> c=0.208953,e=1593683375,V=0,d=4775 1593660200000000000
>
> ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'ovrs,M=91091096
> s=1593683375,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=1,e=1593683479,V=1,d=104
> 1593660200000000000\novrs,M=91091096
> s=1593678600,shift="02-07-20-S2",pc=0.208953,e=1593683375,V=0,d=4775
> 1593660200000000000': bad timestamp"}

Kindly some one help me

I tired the same with Nifi insert also i am facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple points in the INSERT clause. You have to either use separate INSERTS. Or [try to handle a bulk insert](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with-import) using a file.